# Weed identification in Ohio

Tags: identification, weeds

Each group of 5 petals is about the size of a dime or slightly smaller.

[image]

Comment: Just from one photo (and not high resolution) it is difficult. It could be some Gallium

Comment: Very close, but this stuff is hugging the ground like a ground cover plant.  I planted creeping thyme by seed, it is not that for sure.